# Why does my code not display numbers in ordered list?

Tags: html, html-lists

I attempted to code an ordered list using HTML:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor:</p>
  <ul>
    <ol>sit amet</ol>
    <ol>sit amet</ol>
    <ol>sit amet</ol>
  </ul>
```

I tried replacing ul with li:

```html
  <li>
    <ol>sit amet</ol>
    <ol>sit amet</ol>
    <ol>sit amet</ol>
  </li>
```

I still got the same result.
My code does not display either a numbered list or a bullet list, why?

Comment: An ordered list is coded with `<ol>` followed by one or more `<li>` for list items. What you're saying now is to put an ordered list inside of an unordered list, which is not valid.

Comment: if you search for HTML List you get tons of examples of how to format a (numbered) list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ol>` is the top level, stating it's an ordered (numbered) list. `<li>` stands for list item, which is a member of the list.

```
<ol>
  <li>sit amet</li>
  <li>sit amet</li>
  <li>sit amet</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bro to make a bullet list you have to li with every sentence not just at top it will just make a bullet at the top to make a bullet with every sentence write like instead of ol like

```
<li>
  <li>sit amet</li>
  <li>sit amet</li>
  <li>sit amet</li>
</li>
```

And to make a number list
Do

```
<ol>
  <li>sit amet</li>
  <li>sit amet</li>
  <li>sit amet</li>
</ol>
```